# Evitar que un sprite avanze cuando colisione con otros (obstáculos)

Tags: python, pygame

Necesito que el bloque azul que es el jugar que esta en el grupo `bloques` al tocar con alguno del grupo de obstáculos pare pero no e podido con ella y también necesitaría algo de ayuda con la barra de salud que disminuya al recibir una bala.

```
import pygame
import random



Ancho=1200
Alto=600
verde=[0,255,0]
rojo=[255,0,0]
blanco=[255,255,255]
azul=[0,0,255]
negro=[0,0,0]
imagen=[150,150]
salu=100


class Bloques(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,an,al):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image=pygame.Surface([an,al])
        self.image.fill(azul)
        self.rect=self.image.get_rect()
        self.vel_x=0
        self.click=False


    def update(self):
        if self.click:
            self.rect.center=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        self.rect.x+=self.vel_x

class Rival(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image=pygame.Surface([80,50])
        self.image.fill(blanco)
        self.rect=self.image.get_rect()
        self.tmp=random.randrange(80)

    def update(self):
        self.tmp-=1

class Obstaculos(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image=pygame.Surface([40,100])
        self.image.fill(verde)
        self.rect=self.image.get_rect()
        self.vel_y=-4


    def update(self):
        if self.rect.bottom > 550:
            self.vel_y=-4
        if self.rect.y<50:
            self.vel_y=4
        self.rect.y+=self.vel_y

class Bala(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image=pygame.Surface([10,15])
        self.image.fill(rojo)
        self.rect=self.image.get_rect()
        self.vel_y=9

    def update(self):
        self.rect.y+=self.vel_y

class Salud(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,sal,nob):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image=pygame.Surface([sal,nob])
        self.image.fill(verde)
        self.rect=self.image.get_rect()

    def update(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':

    pygame.init()
    pantalla=pygame.display.set_mode([Ancho,Alto])

    #Creacion de los bloques
    bloques=pygame.sprite.Group()
    b1=Bloques(60,60)
    b1.rect.x=random.randrange(0,100)
    b1.rect.y=random.randrange(50,400)
    bloques.add(b1)

    obstaculos=pygame.sprite.Group()
    rivales=pygame.sprite.Group()
    for i in range(1,5):
        r=Rival()
        r.rect.x=i*200
        r.rect.y=500
        rivales.add(r)
        o=Obstaculos()
        o.rect.x=r.rect.right
        o.rect.y=random.randrange(100,500)
        obstaculos.add(o)

    balas=pygame.sprite.Group()
    salud=pygame.sprite.Group()
    s=Salud(100,15)
    s.rect.x=20
    s.rect.y=570
    salud.add(s)

    reloj=pygame.time.Clock()
    fin=False

    while not fin:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                fin=True
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if b1.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    b1.click=True
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                b1.click=False
            if b1.click==False:
                b1.vel_x=+1

        for r in rivales:
            if r.tmp <0:
                b=Bala()
                b.rect.x=r.rect.x+(r.rect.width)/2
                b.rect.y=r.rect.y
                b.vel_y=-7
                balas.add(b)
                r.tmp=80

        for b in balas:
            col_j1=pygame.sprite.spritecollide(b,bloques,True)
            for r in col_j1:
                balas.remove(b)
            if b.rect.y<(50):
                balas.remove(b)
            bloques.add(b1)

        ls_col=pygame.sprite.spritecollide(b1,obstaculos,False)
        for b in ls_col:
            if(b1.vel_x>0):
                b1.rect.right=o.rect.left
                #b1.rect.top=o.rect.bottom
                #b1.rect.bottom=o.rect.top


        bloques.update()
        rivales.update()
        balas.update()
        salud.update()
        obstaculos.update()
        pantalla.fill(negro)
        obstaculos.draw(pantalla)
        bloques.draw(pantalla)
        rivales.draw(pantalla)
        balas.draw(pantalla)
        salud.draw(pantalla)
        pygame.display.flip()
        reloj.tick(60)
```

Comment: Hola Wilmer, bienvenido a [es.so]. Me surge algunas dudas, si lo he entendido quieres evitar que el jugador pueda avanzar al "chocar" con el obstáculo móvil, ahora bien ¿Qué se supone que debe ocurrir si la colisión es lateral? ¿Se desplaza el sprite del jugador arrastrado por el obstáculo?¿Se bloquea el obstáculo?¿Se produce daño en el jugador?¿Se desplaza detrás o delante del obstáculo?...

Comment: La otra duda es el control del jugador, ¿se mueve arrastrando con el ratón pero además se mueve automáticamente hacia delante cuando no es arrastrado ?¿La velocidad de movimiento está limitada o el único límite son los obstáculos?

Comment: El jugador se mueve solo avanzando en x al tocar con el obstáculo se retiene hasta que ya no tiene contacto con el y sigue el camino y recibe daño de las balas que que suben y la velocidad sigue siendo la misma con la que estaba antes de colicionar

Comment: Aunque solo se pueda mover en ej eje x sigue existiendo la posibilidad de chocar con el lateral del obstáculo (más bien que el obstáculo choque con el jugador, ya que los obstáculos se mueven en el eje y constantemente), esa es la duda principal, ¿Qué ocurre si el obstáculo colisiona por arriba o por abajo del jugador y no por delante o por detrás?

Comment: Otra cosa, veo que el jugador tiene su propio grupo de sprites, así como la barra de "vida". Si solo va a haber un sprite jugador y su barra de salud al mismo tiempo el incluirlos en un grupo dificulta las cosas sin necesidad, a no ser que tengas una razón para ello. ¿Acaso vas a tener varios `Rivales` cada uno asociado a su barra de vida que aparecerán concurrentemente, por turnos, etc? ¿O es otra la idea? Siento ser tan pesado :), pero son detalles que pueden cambian significativamente la forma de afrontar el problema.

Comment: la vida es solo del jugador solo que se pidio que los rivales dispararan y si impactan con el jugador reducir la vida en 5 peor la vida tiene que ser una clase aparte no puesta en el sprite de jugador y con lo de chocar en otros lados pues si se puede organizar el del lateral ya podria saber como organizar el de los otros lados pues pensaba que si toca ya en la parte inferior del jugador el bloque cambiaria de dirección